# How to import a published Web app from azure to visual studio for web

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

How do I download a copy of my published Web application from azure to visual studio for web or windows ?
I am using visual studio for web 2013 and also have visual studio desktop app 2015.

Kindly help..
I also cant find the option ->  File -> open -> Web site from azure websites.. option in visual studio desktop app 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If your web application is deployed in Azure web applications then you can get your code by FTP or sFTP.
OR if your web application is deployed as a cloud service then you can get your code by connecting to your instance and get your code and open it as a website on your visual studio.